# create variable from annotation argument

Tags: c#, annotations

I'm trying to save the argument from an custom annotation ( UrlAnnotation ) to be able to use it across classes.

But unfortunately I cannot make it to work in a simple way :/

This is how I'm trying to solve it.

**Test.cs**

```
[UrlAnnotation("customer"])
[TestMethod]
public void Smoke(){
 ....
}
```

**UrlAnnitation.cs**

```
public class UrlAnnotation : Attribute
 {
  private string baseUrl;

  public UrlAnnotation(string baseUrl)
  {
   this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
  }
 }
```

Later I'm trying to access baseUrl (annotation argument) like this.

```
**Uri.cs**

public class Uri {

   private UrlAnnotation urlAnnotation;

   public Uri()
    {
      urlAnnotation = new UrlAnnotation();
    }
 }
```

The error that is thrown is from 
    **urlAnnotation = new UrlAnnotation();**
because It wants an argument, make sense but I don't really know how to add the argument from the annotation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How does `Smoke` relate to `Uri`?

Comment: You need to use reflection to get the attribute instance.

Comment: Do you really need to use attributes? Looks like a string const would suit here.

Comment: As mentioned above you need to use reflection. The value you want is attached to the method Smoke() not to anything else. To get the value you get an instance of the class that contains Smoke and from there get the Custom attribute of the method, and then ask for the variable inside it.

Comment: @DavidG I though that it could be nice to see if the test is running on a customer or others. but maybe you are right.

Comment: @soynerdito thank you for clarification. Yes that was i was struggle with. to understand if the value where attached to a method. Maybe this is not a good solution since i will have different method namses

Comment: There seems to be no relation between the `Uri`-class and your `Smoke`-method, so why should your program *construct* any by relying on something that is only attached to the latter?

Comment: "running on customer or others": that doesn't make sense to me. Attributes are set at compile time, you will get the same values regardless of where the app is running.